Work verification: Integral of $f(x, y, z) = x^3 + y^3 + z^3$ in the region bounded by the sphere $(x-a)^2 + (y-a)^2 + (z-a)^2 = a^2$
I have to compute the integral $\iiint_V (x^3 + y^3 + z^3) \, dx \, dy \, dz,$ where $V$ is the region bounded by the shpere $(x-a)^2 + (y-a)^2 + (z-a)^2 = a^2$ ($a>0$), that is, $V = \{ (x-a)^2 + (y-a)^2 + (z-a)^2 \leq a^2 \}.$ Here's what I've done:
By performing the change of variables
$$ u = \frac{x-a}{a}, \quad v = \frac{y-a}{a}, \quad w = \frac{z-a}{a}, $$
or equivalently,
$$ x = a(1+u), \quad y = a(1+v), \quad z = a(1+w), $$
the region can be described as $S = \{u^2 + v^2 + w^2 \leq 1\}$ and, since the Jacobian of this change of variables is
$$ \frac{\partial(x, y, z)}{\partial(u, v, w)}(u, v, w) = \det \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a \end{pmatrix} = a^3, $$
the integral becomes
$$ \iiint_V (x^3 + y^3 + z^3) \, dx \, dy \, dz = a^6 \iiint_S \left[(1+u)^3 + (1+v)^3 + (1+w)^3 \right] \, du \, dv \, dw. $$
Expanding the expression in the integral,
$$ (1+u)^3 + (1+v)^3 + (1+w)^3 = (u^3 + v^3 + w^3) + 3(u^2+v^2+w^2) + 3(u+v+w) + 3, $$
and so the integral can be split into four parts:
\begin{align} \iiint_V (x^3 + y^3 + z^3) \, dx \, dy \, dz = a^6 \left[ \iiint_S (u^3 + v^3 + w^3) \, du \, dv \, dw + 3\iiint_S (u^2+v^2+w^2) \, du \, dv \, dw \\ + 3\iiint_S (u+v+ w) \, du \, dv \,dw    + 3\iiint_S du \, dv \, dw \right]. \end{align}
We observe that last integral is just the volume of the unit sphere, or $4\pi/3,$ and the second one can be easily computed in spherical coordinates:
$$ \iiint_S  (u^2 + v^2 + w^2) \, du \, dv \, dw = \int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 \rho^2 · \rho^2 \cos \varphi \, d\rho \, d\varphi \, d\theta = \frac{4\pi}{5}.  $$
The problem comes with the first and third integrals. I suspect that, by symmetry, both are zero, but I'd like to have my attempt at a rigorous argument verified. Let us consider, then, for example, $\iiint_S (u+v+w) \, du \, dv \, dw.$ This integral can be written as the sum of the integrals over the intersections of the sphere with each of the eight open octants $S_{\text{I}}, \dotsc, S_{\text{VIII}}$ (we are discarding some parts of $S,$ those that lie on the coordinate planes, but they have null measure, so this doesn't cause any trouble). Now, it is clear that $S_{\text{VII}} = \Phi(S_{\text{I}}),$ where the map $\Phi \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is the diffeomorphism given by $\Phi(h, k, l) = (-h, -k, -l)$ (which has Jacobian determinant $1$). Therefore, $\iiint_{S_{\text{I}}} (u+v+w) \, du \, dv \, dw = \iiint_{S_{\text{VII}}} (-h-k-l) \, dh \, dk \, dl,$ and hence $\iiint_{S_\text{I}} = -\iiint_{S_\text{VII}}.$ We can proceed analogously for the other octants and obtain that $\iiint_{S_\text{II}} = -\iiint_{S_\text{VIII}},$ $\iiint_{S_\text{III}} = -\iiint_{S_\text{V}}$ and $\iiint_{S_\text{IV}} = -\iiint_{S_\text{VI}}.$ So the eight summands cancel out and $\iiint_S (u+v+w) \, du \, dv \, dw = 0.$
The same line of reasoning works for $\iiint_S (u^3+v^3+w^3) \, du \, dv \, dw = 0.$ Finally,
$$\iiint_ V (x^3 + y^3 +z^3) \, dx \, dy \,dz = a^6 \left[ 3· \frac{4\pi}{5} + 3 · \frac{4\pi}{3} \right] = \frac{32\pi a^6}{5}. $$
Thanks for your help.
